# Is there a formula that i can use to look up a specific value from a column conditioned by values from two other columns from the same table?

Tags: google-sheets, multiple-columns, vlookup

I am using google sheets to create a spreadsheet for my university program, and i want to search up a value from a column and it also being conditioned by student name and week ( these values are in separate columns). I want to know if there is a way i can look up a value in a column and conditioned to values from other  columns in the same table.

I have used multiple formulas such as: VLOOKUP, IF & AND, QUERY but they all end up coming as error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include example sheet and be very specific about your input data and desired output in both your question and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with FILTER. For example:

```
=FILTER(A:A,B:B="Example Name",C:C>345)
```

You can add more conditions, and change the first A:A to more include columns in the resultm If you only want to find the first value, wrap it in INDEX:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(....),1)
```